# How to create the command in bash?

Tags: bash

Are there ways to create my own command in bash, except copy of the script in the /bin and create an alias?

Comment: http://tldp.org/LDP/Bash-Beginners-Guide/html/sect_11_02.html :)

Comment: Could you explain some more what you mean by "commmand in bash"?

Comment: @Rinzwind I think OP means running a command (script) by just the script's name.

Comment: $PATH includes much more than only `/bin`, also `~/bin` for example (and `/bin` is not where you should copy your script to), but that's probably not what you are looking for?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean that:

```
function my_command {
   echo "Blah $1 bleh $2"
}
```

and then

```
my_command a b
```

?

Of course you must load this function somehow, usually by including from `~/.bashrc`. Frequent idiom is putting sth like

```
for i in $HOME/.bash.d/*.sh; do
    source $i
done
```

on the end of your `~/.bashrc`, then every file you put into `~/.bash.d/` will be sourced (say you may create your command in `~/.bash.d/my_command.sh`). For system-wide installation `/etc/profile.d` or `/etc/sysprofile.d` may exist in your system (or you may add them in the same way manually if they not, by editing `/etc/profile`).

Answer (score 0):

Create a bash script in your `/usr/bin` folder, it should look something like this

```
#!/bin/bash
# Whatever combination of commands you want to run.
```

Name the bash script what you want to type in to the terminal and make it excecutable:

```
chmod +x filename
```